# InfoPath Form URL TO PDF using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint, infopath

I want to convert inforpath to pdf.

I have the url and have an access to the hosted place like :

```
http://hostserver/PWA/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/PWA/InfoPath%20Title.xml
```

Is there a way to read the InfoPath form as xml and converting it to pdf ?

Comment: What is the content of infopathtitle? It has html or you want xml tags to be printed in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and parse content of the URL to an object via: XElement, HtmlAgilityPack then create PDF file e.g. using TextWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how and where you want to deal with it, ABCPdf,ItextSharp along with many other third party tools available let you handle the conversion on server side.

You can use jspdf or equivalent to do it on client side, analyse what you need and choose your tool.